# Android Email application - Is it possible to get all the details which are configured in Email application

Tags: android, email

Is there any way to get in the code:

Email id
Password
SMTP host
SMTP port

which the user used to setup his Email account with the Android built in Email application

Required because, I am written a MailSender class using JavaMail API there I need to send the mail using the details what user configured in Built in Android Email application.

Comment: It's not possible, as Cytown mentions. Also note that the user may be using Gmail instead of the native email client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not accessible by other apps.

Comment: hi,
       I am also facing same problem atleast can i open the respective compose page of Email application? it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using a valid gmail account and password, and it seems to work.
check [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2208335#2208335)